# SQL: duplicate key value violates unique constraint PGS-220000

Tags: sql, postgresql

Is there a way to perform an sql update on any records where the keys are not violated.

```
UPDATE NmsSubscription SET iRecipientId  = 13251076 WHERE iRecipientId  = 13250626";
```

> 26/09/2022 15:54:44  js15  WDB-200001 SQL statement 'UPDATE
> NmsSubscription SET iRecipientId  = 13251076 WHERE iRecipientId  =
> 13250626' could not be executed. 26/09/2022 15:54:44  js15  PGS-220000
> PostgreSQL error: ERROR:  duplicate key value violates unique
> constraint "nmssubscription_subscription" DETAIL:  Key (iserviceid,
> irecipientid)=(3218161, 13251076) already exists. .

In this table, I successfuly updated 10 records, but there was one service the user was already registered to, hence the error came up, whats the best way to perform the update on any record that is not existing?

Subscriptions for user **13250626**

[image]

Subscriptions for user **13251076**

[image]

I want to assign all subscriptions from recipien 13250626 to recipient 13251076 where the latter is not already subscribed to.

Also I am trying to count the subscriptions recipient 13251076 is not registered to that recipient 13250626 is but i am not getting a correct result.

```
SELECT COUNT(*) FROM NmsSubscription WHERE iRecipientId = 13250626 AND NOT EXISTS (SELECT * FROM NmsSubscription WHERE iRecipientId = 13251076)'
```

Comment: `AND NOT EXISTS (SELECT 1 from NmsSubscription where RecipiendIT=newId)`. Don't use storage type prefixes in column names, that's considered an ugly bug since 2000. Why change the column name if you go from int to long or serial? The data didn't change. The relations didn't change

Comment: Is there a difference if I use select * `UPDATE NmsSubscription SET iRecipientId = 13251076 WHERE iRecipientId = 13250626 AND NOT EXISTS (SELECT * FROM NmsSubscription WHERE iRecipientId = 13251076)`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Admittedly I'm a little unclear of then nature of why you want to do these updates, but if you are updating records except those that already exist due to a PK constraint, then you can remove those from the update using an anti-join (not exists) clause:

```
UPDATE NmsSubscription a
SET iRecipientId = 13251076
WHERE iRecipientId  = 13250626
and not exists (
  select null
  from NmsSubscription b
  where
    a.iserviceid = b.iserviceid and
    b.iRecipientId = 13251076
)
```

It may be a little easier to read using parameters:

```
UPDATE NmsSubscription a
SET iRecipientId = :NEW_VALUE
WHERE iRecipientId  = :OLD_VALUE
and not exists (
  select null
  from NmsSubscription b
  where
    a.iserviceid = b.iserviceid and
    b.iRecipientId = :NEW_VALUE
)
```